# @selector with multiple arguments

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

first my code:

```
   - (NSMenu*)sourceList:(PXSourceList*)aSourceList menuForEvent:(NSEvent*)theEvent item:(id)item
    {
     if ([theEvent type] == NSRightMouseDown || ([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDown && ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask) == NSControlKeyMask)) {
      NSMenu * m = [[NSMenu alloc] init];  
      if (item != nil) {
       NSLog(@"%@",[item title]);

       [m addItemWithTitle:[item title] action:@selector(press:) keyEquivalent:@""]; // problem. i want to give "item" as an argument.....

       for (NSMenuItem* i in [m itemArray]) {
        [i setTarget:self];
       }
      } else {
       [m addItemWithTitle:@"clicked outside" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
      }
      return [m autorelease];
     }
     return nil;
    }
-(void) press:(id)sender{
 NSLog(@"PRESS");
}
```

I want to give `item` as an argument to my `press:` method with a selector.

Thank you very much :)

PS: I'm doing this for the mac not iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSMenuItem has a method called `setRepresentedObject:`, and the menu item object will be passed as the `sender` parameter to `press:` method.

So you need to adjust your code to call `setRepresentedObject:` with the `item` that goes with each `NSMenuItem`, and then in `press:` you can call `[sender representedObject]` to get that item back.

Comment: +1 whoops, I missed that `item` was different than the `NSMenuItem`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm almost positive that the "sender" parameter that is included with the `@selector(press:)` message *is* the `NSMenuItem`.

So:

```
- (void) press:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"sender: %@", sender);
}
```

That should log that the sender is the `NSMenuItem` that was selected.

**edit** misinterpreted the question...

You want to retrieve the `item` object when a certain menuItem is selected.  That's easy.  Just do:

```
NSMenuItem * menuItem = [m addItemWithTitle:[item title] action:@selector(press:) keyEquivalent:@""];
[menuItem setTarget:self];
[menuItem setRepresentedObject:item];
```

Then in your `press:` method...

```
- (void) press:(id)sender {
  //sender is the NSMenuItem
  id selectedItem = [sender representedObject];
}
```

Comment: item is NOT NSMenuItem. item is a custom class from me. It doesnt subclass nsmenuitem

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner yes, I realized that when I read @grahamparks' answer.  I've edited mine for more clarity

Comment: Thank you very much it worked +1. grahampark's gets the accepeted answer because he was faster.